# Найти два элемента из списка с самой большой разницей между значениями

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, numpy

Имеется такой список:

```
empty_rows = [73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102]
```

Нужно найти два значения из этого списка, которые стоят рядом и имеют самую большую разницу в этом списке между собой. В данном случае это значения `81` и `97`, которые имеют разницу в `16`. Какой способ лучше всего использовать, чтобы получить числа `81` и `97`?

Так как у меня уже используется библиотека `numpy`, то я решил использовать её и здесь, хотя решение без этой библиотеки, возможно, будет более подходящим. У меня же тут костыли.

```
# Вернёт [ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  16  1  1  1  1  1  1 ]
diffs = np.diff(empty_rows)

# Вернёт 8 (позицию числа 16 в diffs)
max_diff_index = int(np.where(diffs == max(diffs))[0])

# Получит числа 81 и 97 из empty_rows по индексу
result = empty_rows[max_diff_index], empty_rows[max_diff_index + 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать `numpy`, то можно немного упростить запись

```
max_diff_index = int(np.where(diffs == max(diffs))[0])
```

если использовать функцию `argmax`:

```
max_diff_index = np.argmax(diffs)
```

В итоге код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
index = np.argmax(np.diff(empty_rows))
result = empty_rows[index], empty_rows[index + 1]
```

Если неубывание значений списка не гарантируется, нужно использовать взятие по модулю (`np.abs`) после вычисления разниц элементов:

```
index = np.argmax(np.abs(np.diff(empty_rows)))
#                 ^
result = empty_rows[index], empty_rows[index + 1]
```

При использовании этого решения важно понимать, что будет возвращена только первая пара с максимальной разницей:

```
lst = [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]
index = np.argmax(np.abs(np.diff(lst)))
print(lst[index], lst[index + 1])  # 2 5, хотя есть и 6 9
```

---

Если использовать чистый Python, то для удобства можно определить функцию, возвращающую последовательные пары чисел, после чего найти максимум по разнице чисел:

```
import itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


result = max(pairwise([1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]), key=lambda v: abs(v[1] - v[0]))
```

---

Чтобы найти все максимумы, будет проще дважды проитерироваться по списку последовательных пар:

```
def all_max_diffs(pairs):
    max_diff = max(abs(a - b) for a, b in pairs)
    return ((a, b) for a, b in pairs if abs(a - b) == max_diff)

list(all_max_diffs(list(pairwise([1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]))))  # [(2, 5), (6, 9)]
```